# Could a pure-transverse acoustical-wave propagate?

Tags: waves, acoustics, friction, definition

This is the Wikipedia definition of acoustic waves:

> [Acoustic waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_wave) are a type of energy propagation through a medium by means of adiabatic compression and decompression

**[Rayleigh surface waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_wave)** (solid-surface-borne sounds) are a mix of transverse and longitudinal mechanical waves which propagates through compression/decompression, so they **are acoustical** by definition.

However, what about the **transverse component alone** of a solid-surface-borne mechanical wave (e.g. [seismic S-wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_wave))? While there are compression and decompression along the transverse component, **there isn't any compression/decompression of particle in the direction of propagation** (longitudinal). So I have 3 related questions:

1. **Do *pure* transversal mechanical wave exist in practice** or is there always a small component of longitudinal wave that allows the propagation with compression/decompression?
2. **If it is possible to have no longitudinal component at all in mechanical *pure*-transverse waves, how do they propagate?**
3. I guess the wave could propagate through the friction of particles that belong to a different transverse plane. In this case, since **the propagation is not directly performed through compression/decompression** but via friction, **could we say that *pure* transversal mechanical waves are *not* part of acoustics?**

Some [animations](https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/demos/waves/wavemotion.html) of longitudinal, transversal or a mix of the two help to think about it.

Comment: First, I don't know if there is a universally accepted definition of acoustics.  Second, while I imagine that any real wave would have a combination of both transverse and longitudinal in some degree, there do exist waves that are dominated by the transverse component.  For example, I believe that some tissues support shear waves but only weakly support longitudinal, but I am not an expert there.

Comment: In an ideal case, how could a pure-transversal acoustic wave propagate if there is no longitudinal component (i.e. no compression/rarefaction to propagate)? Actually, could it even exist theoretically?

Comment: One idea is to consider infinitesimal transverse disturbances of a taut string.  In the limit of infinitesimal displacements the string moves exclusively in the transverse direction.

Comment: @Noil Normal stresses (which cause volumetric changes) aren’t the only way to apply stress on a region. Shear stresses (which don’t cause volumetric changes for certain crystal symmetries) also exist. It sounds like some study of this topic in introductory elasticity or mechanics-of-materials texts would prove helpful to clarify why a shear wave is a valid wave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a misconception to hold that shear isn't a way for a general material to be loaded or for a wave to propagate, or that materials generally resist shear deformation through friction, or that [S-waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_wave) are surface waves (rather, they are body waves).

Note that some of these statements are true for ideal fluids, which have a shear modulus of zero; that is, any infinitesimal shear stress is completely (and fairly quickly) relieved through flow as mediated by the viscosity. There are no long-range S-waves in fluids.

However, solids and so-called complex fluids can indeed have a well-defined shear stiffness; these materials maintain a resistance not only to *dilatational* loads (i.e., compressive loads) that tend to change the material's size but also to *deviatoric* loads (i.e., shear loads) that tend to change the material's shape. Broadly, this stiffness arises from long chains of bonding that maintain long-range order. (This effect is distinct from friction, which does not typically refer to cohesive forces within materials.)

A further nuance is that for some crystal symmetries (or lack thereof), a shear stress can cause both shear and normal strains. For simplicity, and since it doesn't alter the main thrust of this answer, let's assume sufficient symmetry (e.g., [orthotropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity#Anisotropic_homogeneous_media)) such that normal stresses produce only normal strains and shear stresses produce only same-plane shear strains.

Thus, applying a shear or tractional load to some plane of a material causes the adjacent region to change shape, as mediated by the [shear modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_modulus). Since that region is bonded in place, fully three other loads must arise on the side of any constituent element to prevent it from translating or rotating:

[image]  

[image]

This is the essence of the shear stress state.

In turn, the tractional loads tend to shear the adjacent regions and then *their* adjacent regions, as mediated in part by their inertia (i.e., their density). This is the essence of the S-wave, whose velocity increases with increasing shear modulus and decreasing density.

The definition of an "acoustical wave" is merely a matter of convention; I'd be interested to see if any reference excludes shear waves other than Wikipedia, the encyclopedia that anyone can edit™. What other examples have you found in your research?